# Java - Indica si un año es bisiesto o no

Tags: java, año-bisiesto

Estoy realizando un programa para indicar si un año es bisiesto o no.

Llevo varías horas trabajando en el código y al fin creo que lo tengo, pero tengo dudas en si es la forma adecuada.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Introduce el año: ");
    int anio = sn.nextInt();
    
    if ((anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 != 0) || (anio % 100 == 0 && anio % 400 == 0))
        
    {
    System.out.println("El año " + anio + " es bisiesto");
    
} else 
    {
        System.out.println("El año " + anio + " no es bisiesto");
    }
}
```

He estado pensando en la alternativa del calendario gregoriano, ¿Qué opináis?

Un saludo!

Comment: Evita usar las clases java.util.Date y Calendar/GregorianCalendar, son anticuallas de las primeras versiones de Java que se mantienen en el API estándar por retrocompatibilidad. Usando el *nuevo* paquete java.time.*` puedes resolverlo con una sóla linea: [`boolean esBisiesto = java.time.Year.isLeap(anio);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html#isLeap(long))

Comment: Gracias por la información Pablo, no tenía conocimiento sobre esto.

Comment: El ejercicio se resuelve usando matemáticas simples. Los años bisiestos se dividen en 2 tipos: *seculares* y *no seculares*. Basta comprobar su divisibilidad entre 4, todos los bisiestos *no seculares* son divisibles entre 4, pero los *seculares* (terminados en 00) serán bisiestos sólo si son divisibles entre 400. Claro, como te comentan, no hace falta reinventar la rueda. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir de Java 8 existe la clase `Year` en el paquete `java.time`, que tiene un método estático para comprobar si un año es bisiesto de acuerdo con el estándar ISO 8601.

De forma que tu código se puede simplificar del siguiente modo:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Introduce el año: ");
    long anio = sn.nextLong();
    
    if (Year.isLeap(anio)) {
        System.out.println("El año " + anio + " es bisiesto");
    } else {
        System.out.println("El año " + anio + " no es bisiesto");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias! No tenía idea. Es una buena alternativa, ya que el código queda simplificado y a mi parecer es más cómodo.

Comment: @pabl1ku Si la respuesta es la correcta, por favor márcala como "correcta" para que quede cerrada. No es recomendable usar los comentarios para dar las gracias o indicar que una respuesta es correcta. Mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers para más información.